# Is grouping in dataframe based on specific parameters possible using Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

When you have a large data set in excel (xlsx, csv, or xls) and have certain repeating values that you have to select for, how do you do it? That's like a very vague and broad way of stating it so...

Take this example:

DataFrame1:

```
**Name**    **No.**      **Comment**       
Bob        2123320     Doesn't Matter   
Joe        2832883     Whatever           
John       2139300     Irrelevant        
Bob        2123320     Something          
John       2234903     Regardless
```

DataFrame2:

```
**Name**    **No.**      **Report**       
Bob        2123320         Great 
Joe        2832883         Solid           
John       2139300        Awesome        
Bob        2123320         Good          
John       2234903        Perfect
```

I am basically looking for a way to only select No.'s that have appeared twice for one name and then list them out like this:

```
**Name**         **2139300**   **2139300**   **2234903**  **2234903**
 John            Irrelevant      Awesome      Regardless    Perfect
```

So basically it looks for each name, and then for each name it looks to see how many distinct No.'s it has, and for each distinct No.'s, it searches for what the "Comment" and "Report" is and then ouputs an excel sheet like above. Although Bob appeared twice, since both times he had the same No., it doesn't count and John is the only relevant person.

Is there a way to do this once imported into a dataframe using Pandas, like perhaps by using a dictionary that counts each No. for each name and then merging the dataframes?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
df_out = pd.concat([df1,df2])
df_out = (df_out[df_out.groupby(['Name'])['No.'].transform(lambda x: x.nunique() > 1)]
              .reset_index(drop=True)
              .set_index(['Name','No.'], append=True)['Comment']
              .unstack([0,2]))
df_out.columns = df_out.columns.droplevel(0)
df_out
```

Output:

```
No.      2139300     2234903  2139300  2234903
Name                                          
John  Irrelevant  Regardless  Awesome  Perfect
```

Use `reset_index` to get unique index per row, then append 'name' and 'no.' to that index and unstack new row number index and no.to create a multiindex column header, then drop the top level of the column header.

You can use:

```
df_out.rename_axis(None, axis=1).rename_axis(None)
```

To get rid of index names and create a more "clean" table looking dataframe:

```
         2139300     2234903  2139300  2234903
John  Irrelevant  Regardless  Awesome  Perfect
```

Comment: Wow! This works beautifully. Can you give me some tips as to how to just develop my skills overall? Like how did you become so proficient in python.

Comment: @A.Code.1 In my profile, there is a book by Ted Petrou.  And, secondly, answering a lot of Stack Overflow questions. :)  Thank you for the compliments.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

1) Group & unstack dataframe1 and dataframe2 to get the general shape you're going for:

```
dataframe1_transformed = \
    dataframe1.groupby(["**Name**", '**No.**'])['**Comment**'].\
    sum().unstack("**No.**")

dataframe2_transformed = \
    dataframe2.groupby(["**Name**", '**No.**'])['**Comment**'].\
    sum().unstack("**No.**")
```

> dataframe1_transformed

```
**No.** **Name**    2123320                 2139300     2234903     2832883
0       Bob         Doesnt MatterSomething  None        None        None
1       Joe         None                    None        None        Whatever
2       John        None                    Irrelevant  Regardless  None
```

> dataframe2_transformed

```
**No.** **Name**    2123320     2139300 2234903 2832883
0       Bob         GreatGood   None    None    None
1       Joe         None        None    None    Solid
2       John        None        Awesome Perfect None
```

2) Combine them:

```
dataframe_all_transformed = \
    dataframe1_transformed.merge(dataframe2_transformed, 
                                 how='inner', left_index=True,
                                 right_index=True)
```

> dataframe_all_transformed

```
**No.** **Name**    2123320_x               2139300_x       2234903_x   2832883_x   2123320_y   2139300_y   2234903_y   2832883_y
0       Bob         DoesntMatterSomething   None            None        None        GreatGood   None        None        None
1       Joe         None                    None            None        Whatever    None        None        None        Solid
2       John        None                    Irrelevant      Regardless  None        None        Awesome     Perfect     None
```

3) Separately count the number of unique appearances:

```
num_apperances = dataframe1.drop_duplicates(subset=['**Name**', '**No.**']).\
    groupby(['**Name**']).size()

multiple_appearing_names = num_apperances[num_apperances > 1].index
```

4) Filter the combined transformed data just for those names:

```
dataframe_multiple_transformed = dataframe_all_transformed.loc[
    multiple_appearing_names].T.dropna().T
```

5) Technically it's a bad idea to have identical column names in a dataframe, but since you want it:

```
dataframe_multiple_transformed.columns = \
    [x.split("_")[0] for x in dataframe_multiple_transformed.columns]
```

> dataframe_multiple_transformed

```
    **Name**    2139300     2234903     2139300 2234903
0   John        Irrelevant  Regardless  Awesome Perfect
```

Comment: When I get to step 4, it just makes the entire dataframe blank? Is this normal?