# Grouped Feature Matrix in Python #2- Follow Up

Tags: python, excel, pandas, feature-extraction

It's not too different from before. We can start with the sample data:

DataFrame1:

```
Name         No.        Comment    
Bob        2123320     Doesn't Matter   
Joe        2832883     Whatever           
John       2139300     Irrelevant        
Bob        2123320     Something          
John       2234903     Regardless
```

DataFrame2:

```
Name          No.          Report    
Bob        2123320         Great 
Joe        2832883         Solid           
John       2139300        Awesome        
Bob        2123320         Good          
John       2234903        Perfect
```

I am looking for a way to make a new excel file that looks like this (Expected Outcome):

```
     -----------------------2139300---------------------  2234903----                    
Name Irrelevant Whatever Regardless Awesome Solid Perfect  Irrelevant \
John    1          0       0          1      0     0         0
      --------------------2234903-------------
Name Whatever Regardless Awesome Solid Perfect  
John    0       1         0        0      1
```

(Note: It doesn't need to have the head-titles of the No., I just did that for clarity and later explanation).

Basically what I have done is, very similar to the other, looks for each name, and then for each name it looks to see how many distinct No.'s it has. It then selects for people who have a certain amount of distinct No.'s. **Now, I have a set of "Comments" and "Reports" I wish to look for 
({Irrelevant, Whatever, Regardless} and {Awesome, Solid, Perfect} respectively [note: this is only a subset of Comments/Reports]) and for these I want to have a 1 or 0 if it appears but only for each No. Put another way, I want for each No. to have a "group" of columns titled {Irrelevant, Whatever, Regardless} and {Awesome, Solid, Perfect} and for each value I want a 1 if it appeared for the person for that Specific No. and a 0 if it didn't.**

In this matrix, for example, we only see John because he is the only one with more than 1 distinct No. In the first group of columns only Irrelevant and Awesome have values of 1 whereas the rest have 0 and in the second group only Regardless and Perfect will have 1s. What it did was it listed all of my desired Comments/Reports ({Irrelevant, Whatever, Regardless} and {Awesome, Solid, Perfect}) for only one No. and then found out if each appeared or not (1 or 0). It then repeated all the desired Comments/Reports in a new "group" of columns for a new No. and for this new No. found out which Comments/Reports now appeared.

Let me know if anything is unclear and I truly do appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df_out = df_out[df_out.groupby(['Name'])['No.'].transform(lambda x: x.nunique() > 1)]\
   .set_index(['Name','No.'])['Comment'].str.get_dummies()\
   .reindex(df_out.Comment, fill_value=0, axis=1)\
   .sum(level=[0,1])\
   .unstack()\
   .swaplevel(0,1,axis=1)\
   .sort_index(1)

print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
No.     2139300                                                                \
Comment Awesome Doesn't Matter Good Great Irrelevant Perfect Regardless Solid   
Name                                                                            
John          1              0    0     0          1       0          0     0   

No.                        2234903                                       \
Comment Something Whatever Awesome Doesn't Matter Good Great Irrelevant   
Name                                                                      
John            0        0       0              0    0     0          0   

No.                                                  
Comment Perfect Regardless Solid Something Whatever  
Name                                                 
John          1          1     0         0        0  

​
```

Comment: Incredibly amazing! Thank you so much

Comment: @A.Code.1 You're welcome.   Sorry, I had you repost, but sometimes see the desired output makes more sense than words.   Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks again. I really love your coding method and descriptions. I had another question that I was still unclear on relating to a similar problem at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503422/is-grouping-in-dataframe-based-on-specific-parameters-possible-using-python . Do you think you might be able to take a crack at that

Comment: Hey man. I really feel bad in bombarding you with so many questions in such a little time, but I decided to try and add another dimension to this problem. I decided to create a new post explicitly describing inputs and outputs and would really appreciate if you had any time to check it out at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49763973/multiply-indexes-for-dataframe-grouping