# Multiple Indexes for Dataframe Grouping

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I'll just start with the example and then break down what is happening.

This is a sample input:

DataFrame:

```
**Name**    **No.**      **Test**       ***Grade***
Bob        2123320        Math             Nan
Joe        2832883       English           90
John       2139300       Science           85
Bob        2123320        History          93
John       2234903        Math             99
```

Hopeful output:

```
**Name**         ********2139300*********     ********2234903*******
                  Math   English  Science     Math   English  Science 
  John            0       0         85        99        0          0
```

Like the title suggests, I am trying to apply multiple indexes. So basically it starts by looking for each name, and then for each name it finds to see how many distinct No.'s it has. In this case it sets a threshold at at least 2 distinct No.'s (which is why only John is outputted and Joe/Bob are not).

Now in each of these distinct No's. I have a specific subset of Tests I want to search for, in this case only {Math, English, Science}. For each of these tests, if the person in question took it in that No., there should be a grade. I would like that grade to be outputted for the test in question and for the tests not taken by that person on that No. I would like it to output some sort of simple marker (i.e if the person only took Math on that day, for English and Science output 0).

So in effect, it first indexes people by the number of distinct No.'s and groups them as such. It then indexes them by type of Test (for which I only want a subset). It finally assigns each person a value for the type of test they took and for the ones they didn't simply outputs an 0.

It's similar to another problem I asked earlier:
[Grouped Feature Matrix in Python #2- Follow Up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49744958/grouped-feature-matrix-in-python-2-follow-up)

Except now instead of 1's and 0's I have another column with actual values that I would like to output.

Thank you.

EDIT: More sample/Output

```
 **Name**    **No.**      **Test**       ***Grade***
Bob        2123320        Math             Nan
Joe        2832883       English           90
John       2139300       Science           85
Bob        2123320        History          93
John       2234903        Math             99
Bob        2932848         English         99


  **Name**    2139300        2234903       2123320      2932848
          M   E    S      M   E    S    M   E    S    M   E    S
  John    0   0    85    99   0    0   Nan  Nan  Nan  Nan  Nan Nan
  Bob     Nan Nan  Nan   Nan  nan  Nan 86   0    0    0    99  0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use:

Filter the dataframe to only those records you are concerned with

```
df_out = df[df.groupby(['Name'])['No.'].transform(lambda x: x.nunique() > 1)]
```

Now, reshape dataframe with `set_index`, `unstack`, and `reindex`:

```
df_out.set_index(['Name','No.','Test'])['Grade'].sum(level=[0,1,2])\
      .unstack(-1, fill_value=0)\
      .reindex(['Math','English','Science'], axis=1, fill_value=0)\
      .unstack(-1, fill_value=0).swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1)\
      .sort_index(1)
```

Output:

```
No.  2123320              2139300              2234903              2932848             
Test English Math Science English Math Science English Math Science English Math Science
Name                                                                                    
Bob        0    0       0       0    0       0       0    0       0      99    0       0
John       0    0       0       0    0      85       0   99       0       0    0       0
```

Comment: Thank you so much again. Real quick: I ran this, and I got an error message: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape. Are the duplicate entries still present?

Comment: Actually, can you add a bit more data to the question.

Comment: For some reason the error is still there. How would pivot_table be used? Thank you.

Comment: @A.Code.1 Sorry, I was pretty tired last night, didn't want to leave you with an incorrect solution.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate that. Quick question: The code runs now but all the values now output as 0's somehow.

Comment: My bad, I just realized that comment was vague. I meant all the values that I would like Nan are 0

Comment: remove the `fill_value` parameter for `unstack` methods.

Comment: This seems to give me now only values of 0 and blank for all other cells.  I apologize for this taking so much of your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
In [11]: df.pivot_table(values="Grade", index=["Name"], columns=["No.", "Test"])
Out[11]:
No.  2123320 2139300 2234903 2832883
Test History Science    Math English
Name
Bob     93.0     NaN     NaN     NaN
Joe      NaN     NaN     NaN    90.0
John     NaN    85.0    99.0     NaN
```

With the dropna flag to include all the NaN columns:

```
In [12]: df.pivot_table(values="Grade", index=["Name"], columns=["No.", "Test"], dropna=False)
Out[12]:
No.  2123320                      2139300                      2234903                       2832883
Test English History Math Science English History Math Science English History  Math Science English History Math Science
Name
Bob      NaN    93.0  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN
Joe      NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   NaN     NaN    90.0     NaN  NaN     NaN
John     NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN    85.0     NaN     NaN  99.0     NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN
```

and with fill_value=0

```
In [13]: df.pivot_table(values="Grade", index=["Name"], columns=["No.", "Test"], dropna=False, fill_value=0)
Out[13]:
No.  2123320                      2139300                      2234903                      2832883
Test English History Math Science English History Math Science English History Math Science English History Math Science
Name
Bob        0      93    0       0       0       0    0       0       0       0    0       0       0       0    0       0
Joe        0       0    0       0       0       0    0       0       0       0    0       0      90       0    0       0
John       0       0    0       0       0       0    0      85       0       0   99       0       0       0    0       0
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I had also mentioned that I was hoping to select for only people with at least 2 distinct No's and also only a subset of the tests. Also I was hoping to mark that on some dates a person may have only taken 1 test with a 0 (or any marker). Are these possible?

Comment: @A.Code.1 that's definitely possible, you can use the `fill_value=0` in the pivot_table.

Comment: Ah sorry I think I was a little vague. I only wanted to fill certain ones with 0's and keep others blank. For example, take John's 2123320 and 2234903. Because he only took Math on 2234903 I want that to be a 99 and the other 3 columns of that "group" to be 0's only in that row. For his 2123320, I want it to be completely blank because that No. does not belong to John at all. Also is it possible to select for at least 2 distinct No.'s?

Comment: Quick question too. Instead of all "Tests" I just want English Math and Science. How do I only get these 3? Thanks.